# Can I migrate between EC2 instance types using the same EBS volume to boot off of?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have a scheme for a cheap minecraft server using t2 instances. If I want to play with just a few friends, I will use t2.small. If I want to play with a lot of friends I will detach the volume, attach it to a t2.medium and play on that.

From reading the documents and using the AWS Console, it does not appear to be possible to boot off of an existing EBS volume. Is there something I am missing that would make this use case possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the existing EC2 instance between t2.small and t2.medium as needed.

1. Sign-in to the AWS Management Console, EC2 section
2. Stop your EC2 instance
3. Change the instance type to the desired instance type
4. Restart the EC2 instance

Note that if your EC2 instance is in EC2-Classic (ie. not inside a VPC), then you will get a new IP address. You can preserve an IP address by using an Elastic IP address.

Comment: Ah, thank you! For future people you can use the API command ModifyInstanceAttribute to change the InstanceType.

Comment: Yes, but the instance still needs to be stopped to make the change. But you can use the API to do that too.